# Windows vista important files

Tags: windows-vista

my hp vista will not power on or neither will the monitor. I have photos that I did not back up. Is there a way to retrieve them I have tried to unplug and restart but nothing happens

Comment: If the drive is not dead it can be removed from your box, attached to another computer, and the files copied off.

Answer (score 0):

If the monitor is plugged into the back of the computer then it's likely the power supply in the computer is dead. Power supplies do often die in older Dell's and HP's. If that is the problem then your pictures can easily be gotten back by having the hard drive pulled and put into it's own USB case.

If the monitor nor the machine power on and they have separate power cords plugged into the same power strip then check to make sure the power strip is on. If the power strip was on, then plug both monitor and computer into another wall outlet and see if they come on then. If so, then you have a problem with the first wall outlet or the power strip.

8 years is time to get a new machine, like was said by me and another, you should be able to easily get back the pictures and other data by having the hard drive put into an external USB case and attaching it to the new machine.

Good luck and shopping for a new machine is usually a fun activity.

(reposted to this newer question from Sheryl's duplicate question)